# Python Beginner, try to learn

Tags: python

I try to figure out why I have the Error

```
<TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'privileges'>
```

#9-7

```
class User:
    def __init__(self, first_name, last_name, age, weight, race):
        self.first_name = first_name
        self.last_name = last_name
        self.age = age
        self.weight = weight
        self.race = race
        self.login = 0

    def describe_user(self):
        print("The following infoation is about this user")
        print(f"\t{self.first_name}")
        print(f"\t{self.last_name}")
        print(f"\t{self.age} years old")
        print(f"\t{self.weight} lbs")
        print(f"\t{self.race}")

    def greet_user(self):
        full_name = f"{self.first_name} {self.last_name}"
        print(f"Nice to meet you {full_name}")

    def login_attempts(self):
        """Print a statement and show the current attempts"""
        print(f"Current login attempt {self.login}")

    def increment_login_attempts(self):
        """Increase login attempt by 1 everytime"""
        self.login += 1

    def reset_login_attempts(self):
        """Resrt the value"""
        self.login = 0


class Privileges:
    def __init__(self, privileges):
        """Initilize attributes to the class"""
        self.privileges = ['can add post', 'can delete post', 'can ban user']   
             
    def show_privileges(self):
        """Show the current priviledges list"""
        print(self.privileges)


class Admin(User):
    def __init__(self, first_name, last_name, age, weight, race):
        """
        Initialize attributes of the parent class.
        Then initizalize attributes specific to an electric car. 
        """
        super().__init__(first_name, last_name, age, weight, race)
        self.privileges = Privileges()


    # def add_privileges(self, privileges):
    #     """Add privileges to the list"""
    #     for privilege in privileges:
    #         self.privileges.append(privilege)


user_01 = Admin('Edward', 'Li', 18, 150, 'Asian')
user_01.privileges.show_privileges()
```

Comment: Please include the full error message.

Comment: Why does your `Privileges.__init__` method take a `privileges` argument that it never uses?

Answer (score 0):

Your `Privileges` class `__init__` method takes an argument, but when you initialize it here:

```
self.privileges = Privileges()
```

You're not giving an argument. That is I believe why you are getting the error.

So either a) remove the parameter OR b) supply something for the parameter

Comment: It doesn't actually use the parameter. So maybe the error is that it requires the argument in the first place.

Comment: @Barmar yeah, removing the parameter would be one fix, I was just pointing out where that error is coming from

Comment: A good answer shouldn't just point out the error, it should explain how to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

`Privileges` requires `privileges` upon initialization, from your definition:

`def __init__(self, privileges):`. I realize you actually assign a value anyway to `privileges`. So have:

```
class Privileges:
    def __init__(self):
```

Instead.